# Swift Mailer does not work and gives no error messages

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer

I try to send emails via Swift-Mailer. According to the documentation, it should work like this, but I neither get a mail nor an error message.

Here is the code of the PHP Swift file:

```
<?php
    require_once '/composer/vendor/autoload.php';

    // Create the Transport
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl'))
    ->setUsername('*******@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('password')
    ;

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
    ->setTo(['infinity.community.work@gmail.com', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
    ;

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
?>
```

And here is the composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again with this syntax and make sure the email or the password are spelt correctly:

```
$trp = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername('*********@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($trp);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
    ->setFrom(['john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'])
    ->setTo(['infinity.community.work@gmail.com', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'])
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself');

$mailer->send($message);
```

**EDIT:** worked successfully with SwiftMailer version **5.4**

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really work either the PHP page crashes directly when creating the new Swift_SmtpTransport instance.

Comment: Ok, i will try.

Comment: Version 5.6 is not available, but I have tried 5.4.9 and it works, thanks